# Creating a new column in an SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datatable, columnsorting

I am working with a table on MySQL that has a timestamp column and I want to extract the date from the column. I know I can use the date function to get the date alone from the column but I want to add a new column to the table with just the date.
Is it possible to extract just the date from the timestamp column and create a new column with it in the process?

Comment: I suggest _not_ even adding such a column.  Just extract the date only component when you need, at the same you do a query.

Comment: So how do I get just the year from the timestamp column

Comment: Use the `YEAR()` function.

Comment: tried the YEAR() function

Answer (score 0):

Use generated column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD COLUMN date_only DATE AS (timestamp_column),
ADD COLUMN year_only YEAR AS (YEAR(timestamp_column));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb479131cd91e604da3f35b6e4a1752a

Comment: @ChuksJoy Remember - you cannot insert or update this column value, you'd skip it in the query or use DEFAULT keyword for this column value.